# How to pass the request before take screenshot with python?

Tags: python, selenium, google-maps, webdriver

I run the code to get maps image as below

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.google.se/maps/@-0.1921083,-78.4865351,17.25z/data=!5m1!1e1')
sleep(1)

driver.get_screenshot_as_file("screenshot.png")
driver.quit()
print("end...")
```

The results is as
[image]

How to get only the maps picture without the dialog in the picture? I try to pass it but it do not work.

the pop up is
[image]

The hltm from the link is as picture[image]

xpath is `/html/body/div/c-wiz/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div/span/span`

I run with new version

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

PATH = "https://www.google.se/maps/@-0.1921083,-78.4865351,17.25z/data=!5m1!1e1"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get(PATH)
sleep(2)
xpath = '/html/body/div/c-wiz/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div/span/span'
print(xpath)
#Xpath=//tagname[@attribute='value']
elem  = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
sleep(1)
elem.click()
sleep(2)
driver.get_screenshot_as_file("screenshot.png")
driver.quit()
print("end...")
```

The error is `NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: /html/body/div/c-wiz/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div/span/span`

Comment: I tried your code and i am not getting the dialog box in my snapshot. Please provide more information related to the said dialog box. What it is asking for?

Comment: I also can not reproduce the problem.

Comment: @SwaroopHumane perhaps, You set up your driver before, and the pop up is not shown. However, I run the code and results is as the picture. :'( I only wanna get the maps.

Comment: @Armadillan you need to download the geckodriver at https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
And then, put the extracted file to python.exe folder. and it works.

Comment: @cnp I am using geckodriver, the code is running correctly. What I'm saying is that running the same code, I do not get the same issue as you. I don't have the popup in my screenshot. Please tell us more about this popup, like Swaroop said.

Comment: @Armadillan please see the update picture.

Comment: @cnp Självklart, you are in the EU, so GDPR mandates cookie popups. On the site, use ctr+i (while hovering over the button) to see the html of the "Jag godkänner" button. Get that element from that page, [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) is how. Then just run the "click" function of that element (`element = somecode; element.click()`).

Comment: @Armadillan I update the xpath and the html picture. Please see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Jag godkänner" button is in a different iframe. Since there is only one iframe in the page, you can just find the first element with the `iframe` tag.

You can also remove all of the `sleep`.

This code works:

```
from selenium import webdriver

PATH = "https://www.google.se/maps/@-0.1921083,-78.4865351,17.25z/data=!5m1!1e1"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get(PATH)
xpath = '/html/body/div/c-wiz/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div/span/span'
print(xpath)

# I added these two lines to your last example:
frame = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe") # Finds iframe
driver.switch_to.frame(frame) # Switches to that iframe

#Xpath=//tagname[@attribute='value']
elem  = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
elem.click()
driver.get_screenshot_as_file("screenshot.png")
driver.quit()
print("end...")
```

Comment: I think the code is good. However, when I run it on my machine. the error is at 'take screenshoot' 

WebDriverException: Message: TypeError: browsingContextFn().currentWindowGlobal is null
it worked with 'driver.switch_to.default_content()'

Comment: @cnp Maybe try switching back to the main frame? Add `driver.switch_to.parent_frame()` before the screenshot line. It shouldn't make a difference, and it works on my machine either way...

Comment: @cnp Nvm, did you say it works when you add `driver.switch_to.default_content()` before the screenshot line? That should have the same effect.